# Add new object to top of a scrollview in titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a layout with a scrollview that has a vertical layout. I adde images taken by the camera to the scroll view. But now what I want to doe is to add the new image to the top of the scrollview instead of the bottom. How can I add an new object to the top of the scrollviews layout?

Comment: can you show some code which you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried because I make no idea how to start to achieve what I won't